# How to use history in a child of BrowserRouter?

Tags: react-router, browser-history, react-router-dom, history.js

I am getting this error:

```
'Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM'
```

I have tried most of the things I managed to find Googling around, nothing seems to work.

Currently my simplified setup is something like that

```
<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={!supportsHistory}>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Where `App` is something like that:

```
import history from './history';

<Router history={history}> // I have to remove Router for it to work at all
    <Switch>
        <Route1 irrelevant/>
        <Route2 irrelevant/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

history.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Route2:

```
import history from './history';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>

export default withRouter(Route2);
```

The only reason I am using history is for that goBack function in my 2nd Route. So if there is an alternative way I am very curious or if there is a way to get the history to work.

Comment: Are you wrapping a router inside another router? I think that can cause conflicts (Not tested it)

Comment: Yup, it seems to be causing problems indeed. Removing `Router` in App makes the routing work fine, BUT I am totally missing history :D
And I cannot change BrowserRouter to Router because of that extra field of `forceRefresh `

Comment: I edited the main question as well with a comment, thanks for noticing :D

Answer (score 0):

To access the history instance controlled by your router you should use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter), that allows you to access router properties:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import React from "react";

  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;

    return <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yea, sorry, I forgot to add that. I already have withRouter added to the export.
I will edit the initial post